# Joining Summary Tables in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have two tables that I would like to join in MYSQL and I'm looking for the most optimized way to do this.  Here's the problem:

I want to count the number of records based on a field (call it customer) in each table then join the results together (using customer) to produce a summary table. Note that all customers must be returned even if one table does not include a customer

```
TABLE A 

Customer 
--------
1
1
4
4
5
6
```

and

```
TABLE B

Customer
--------
4
5
5
5
6
6
7
7
7
```

into a summary table

```
SUMMARY

Customer  CountA CountB
-----------------------
1         2      0
4         2      1
5         1      3
6         1      2 
7         0      3
```

Any ideas on how to do something like this?

Comment: Please update your question with the query that you've tried so we can help you identify what's wrong with it.

Comment: I don't have a query for this yet .. hence why I'm asking for help

Comment: Please read the [How-to-ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) FAQ. You must actually demonstrate some effort.

Comment: read the How-to-ask FAQ .. and nowhere does it say I must actually demonstrate some effort.  Actually it says "Not all questions benefit from including code.."  which in this case posting up some SQL would not actually benefit.  Which is why I posted the source tables and the desired output, pretty much what this statement says "Include just enough code to allow others to reproduce the problem.."

Comment: You probably didn't try the links at the bottom. See [this meta discussion](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/59991/what-are-the-top-issues-when-it-comes-to-low-quality-questions) and Matt's [WHYT](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT customer,SUM(source = 'a') cnta, SUM(source = 'b') cntb FROM
     (
       SELECT 'a' source,customer FROM customer_a
       UNION ALL
       SELECT 'b',customer FROM customer_b
     ) n
 GROUP  
    BY customer;
```

Comment: worked like a charm .. totally forgot that I could use a union here!